# jQuery - get value from a select when there are several

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am dynamically inserting many selects on to my page depending on user inputs.  The select lists are identical and share similar names.

When the user chooses an option, I want to grab that value. (In the end what I'm trying to accomplish is to disable the chosen value from all other lists, but re-enable it if the value is changed.  But one step at a time)

I am assuming that I will need to use `$(this)` but I apparently do not know how to get the values from the second, third lists, and so on.

The HTML would be something like this:

```
<select name="category[first]">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>

<select name="category[second]">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>

** Many more lists with the same naming convention
```

As for my jQuery, I was trying something like this:

```
$('body').on('change', $('select[name^="category"]', function(){
    alert( $(this).find('option:selected').val() );
});
```

But that only gives me the value from the first select, and not from any subsequent ones.  My understanding is that I have to use `$('body')` or `$('document')` since they are dynamically created elements.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: If none of the answers worked or you are still facing trouble, let me know so I can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `$(` before the selector. The selector needs to be a string, not `jQuery` object

```js
$('body').on('change', 'select[name^="category"]', function(){
    console.log( $(this).find('option:selected').val() );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="category[first]">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>

<select name="category[second]">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I see. My inexperience with jQuery/JS is shining brightly here.  Thank you for pointing that out!

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would do it: [**DEMO FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/L6emx5g1/1/)

```
 $('body').on('change', 'select', function () {
     var selected_value = $(this).val();
     $('select option').each(function(){
         if(this.value == selected_value){
             $(this).prop('disabled', true);
         } else {
             $(this).prop('disabled', false);
         }
     });
 });
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me with my next step.  As the other answer helped me solved my problem with my selector issue, I am choosing to go with that as my chosen answer.  But appreciate the help